# webpack5 output.library can't import

Tags: javascript, webpack

#### problem

I use `<script>` to import index.bundle.js which bundled by webpack5 in a HTML.But I failed.

#### option file

```
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: '/src/index.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'test',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    }
}
```

```
//index.ts
export function mount() {
    console.log("mount")
}
```

```
//html
 <script src="dist/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(window.mount());
    </script>
```

#### error

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.mount is not a function
```

#### code

I have checked the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget).But I can't find answer.
my code is [here](https://github.com/clark-cui/webpack-library-example-11986)

### use

```
yarn 
npm run build
```

then open the index.html,you can find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the config you currently have (which is not putting them on the root `window` object), you can access your functions with `window.test.mount()`, because that's what you have in `library` in the webpack config.

If you want to put these functions on the root window object, you'd need to do that in your code:

```
export function mount() {
    console.log("mount")
}
window.mount = mount

// etc.
```

You can see this by checking out `dist/index.js` (dropping it in the [Prettier tool online](https://prettier.io/playground/) can clean it up enough to be readable).

Comment: thanks bro.It did work.Then i find my another problem.that's webpack devServer'problem.

[see here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11986)

finally,i give up to use devServer in this situation. It did work.